# Non-trivial applications of Bloom filters

Tags: ds.data-structures

Does anyone have some nice examples of modifying algorithms that employ a set data structure to instead employ a Bloom filter?  In other words, the damage done by the Bloom filter's false positive rate requires an interesting trick to accommodate.

Comment: What counts as nontrivial ? One classic example is proxy caches, where you just have to fetch the URL explicitly if you get fooled by the bloom filter

Comment: Bloom filters are "obviously a perfect fit" for GoogleFS, proxy caches, etc.  I'm merely curious about less natural applications, like some graph algorithm that needs a big set.  There must be some such algorithms in networking problems I suppose, i.e. you publish some Bloom filter for all nodes to use.

Comment: Have you seen Michael Mitzenmacher's survey ? (moving to an answer)

Comment: No, but that's great! thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Michael Mitzenmacher has a [nice survey on Bloom filters](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~yzhang/teaching/cs386m-f9/Readings/im2005b.pdf) where he outlines many applications. Maybe some of these might help.